# Allowing html code in string output

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

On a razor page I am displaying a string. The string contains a '-' that I would like to replace with a `"<br />"` so that it breaks on the dash.

```
 <h3>@Model.Location.Name.Replace(" - ","<br />")</h3>
```

This of course doesn't work because the system encodes the output so I get

```
Mylocation<br />MyLocation2
```

instead of the desired break.

Is there a way to force the break?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
@Html.Raw("<br />")
```

In your code this would be:

```
<h3>@Html.Raw(@Model.Location.Name.Replace(" - ","<br />"))</h3>
```

Comment: So I ended up with this
'<h3>@Html.Raw(@Model.Location.Name.Replace(" - ","<br />"))</h3>'
 Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @walkhard's answer but provided in the context of your code.

```
<h3>@Html.Raw(@Model.Location.Name.Replace(" - ","<br />"))</h3>
```

Edit: Looks like you got it!